# how should define a PRIMARY KEY in PartiQL at Amazon QLDB?

Tags: amazon-qldb, partiql

I want to define a primary key in QLDB that the query language is PartiQL, how can I define **ID** as a primary key?

```
CREATE TABLE CarInfo WITH (aws_tags = `{ 'ID': INT, 'Manufacturer': STRING, 'ProductionYear': year, 'Model':STRING, 'VIN':STRING, 'Owner': STRING}`);
```

P.S., Since in the document of "Amazon QLDB-Developer Guide" is written "*QLDB supports open content and does not enforce schema, so you don't define attributes or data types when creating tables.*", maybe there is no PRIMARY KEY exsit in the PartiQL?

Comment: hi, try `CREATE INDEX ON CarInfo (ID)`

Comment: Thanks for your help, I have utilized the mentioned commands, but the table is still un-sorted based on ID.
The table is as follow:
1. ....
3. ...
2. ....

Answer (score 4):

your initial assertion is correct -- there is no traditional primary key concept in QLDB at this time. to uniquely identify documents, you can use the [document id](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/qldb/latest/developerguide/ql-reference.docs.html#ql-reference.docs.id). to enforce uniqueness, the current recommendation is to SELECT before INSERT in a transaction to verify that the data being inserted is unique. you'll also want to make sure that the fields you're using to enforce uniqueness/idempotency contain high-cardinality values, so that indexed queries will be optimized ([see more on optimizing here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/qldb/latest/developerguide/working.optimize.html#working.optimize.patterns)).

regarding your comment about sorting, the content within a QLDB index is not sorted and there is currently no support for sorted indexes. as such, you would need to perform application-level sorting. if there are too many rows to feasibly do this, you may consider [streaming](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/qldb/latest/developerguide/streams.html) to a secondary database for sorting and any other analytical queries.